# How to parse string to timespan

Tags: c#, parsing, timespan, days

I want to parse the literal string `01:4:54:28` into a Timespan in but I get error

> Input string is not in a correct format

code :

```
 TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["karkard"].ToString());
```

Comment: `var ts = TimeSpan.Parse("0:4:54:28");` works fine for me; are you perhaps running in a different culture that has different time formats? Also, are you absolutely sure that the string is `"0:4:54:28"`? tip: read it into a variable so you can debug it: `var s = dt.Rows[i]["karkard"].ToString(); TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.Parse(s);`. Note: `0.04:54.28` would be more "normal" here.

Comment: You can also use TimeSpan.TryParse instead

Comment: What's the value of `dt.rows[i]["karkard"]`? Calling `ToString()` and then parsing the result is almost always a bad idea... usually it's better to just cast to the right type and work with that.

Comment: What type is the object in that karkard column?

Comment: In other words, what does `dt.Rows[i]["karkard"].GetType().FullName` say?

Comment: Non of them worked

Answer (score 4):

There are two factors in play in formatting and parsing:

- what *actually* is the value?
- what culture am I in?

For the first, add a variable:

```
string s = dt.Rows[i]["karkard"].ToString();
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.Parse(s);
```

And find out what `s` is in the debugger. If we assume that it *really is* `"0:4:54:28"`, then that *works fine for me*, which suggests culture. You can override the culture via the overload:

```
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

which should work for *anyone*.

Comment: dear  Marc Gravell: I could get response from your answer Please help me more to parse to timespan from  “day:hours:minute:second”

Answer (score 0):

not sure what 01:4:54:28 means, but as far as I know:

1 day, 4 hours, 54 min, 28 seconds is supposed to be "1.04:54:28" in the string

1 hour, 4 minutes, 54 sec, 28 microseconds is supposed to be "1:04:54.28" in the string.

that said, I cant get timespan.parse to work right either...